# how to display long text ( datatype text up to 20 000 characters) in div

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I'm currently enhancing a system using vb.net. My issue is, i need to display a column name 'WONOTE' **(datatype TEXT)** from SQL Server into div in html front screen. The maximum length of characters for this column is up to 22 000 characters. I retrieved the data from SQL server into div by using sql command in code behind. I manage to display the data but only up to 110 characters by using this statement 1:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(cast(WONOTE as varchar(110)), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '')
```

[image]

and up to 10 characters using this statement 2:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), b.WONOTE) as WONOTE
```

[image]

but I need it to display full text. If i change into varchar(max) or anything greater than 110 for statement 1 and 10 for statement 2 it display nothing.

[image]
I wish someone can help me with it.
Thank you in advance.

How i retrieved data from SQL server:

```
Public Sub GETWHATSRUNNING()

    Dim paraWC As SqlParameter
    Dim SQL As String
    Dim myArray, myArray1, myArray2, myArray3,
    myArray4, myArray5, myArray6, myArray7,
    myArray8, myArray9, myArray10 As String

    TempDT.Columns.Add("WO", GetType(String))
    TempDT.Columns.Add("WOQTY", GetType(String))
    TempDT.Columns.Add("PartNum", GetType(String))
    TempDT.Columns.Add("Desc", GetType(String))
    TempDT.Columns.Add("WIPQTY", GetType(String))
    TempDT.Columns.Add("WIPDAYS", GetType(String))
    TempDT.Columns.Add("WOAGING", GetType(String))
    TempDT.Columns.Add("AGINGATWC", GetType(Double))
    TempDT.Columns.Add("COLOR", GetType(String))
    'TempDT.Columns.Add("WO_NOTE", GetType(String))


    WCLimit = 5

    SQL = "select distinct A.WONO, B.BLDQTY , C.PART_NO , C.DESCRIPT, B.Start_Date, REPLACE(REPLACE(cast(WONOTE as varchar(110)), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '') " & _
          "from Transfer A " & _
          "left join WOENTRY B on A.wono = B.wono " & _
          "left join INVENTOR C on B.UNIQ_KEY = C.UNIQ_KEY " & _
          "where FR_DEPT_ID = @WC and start_date is not null " & _
          "and B.BLDQTY <> B.COMPLETE "

    GetConnection()
    oConnSql = New SqlConnection(connString.ToString)
    oCmdSql = New SqlCommand(SQL, oConnSql)
    paraWC = New SqlParameter("@WC", SqlDbType.VarChar, 5)
    paraWC.Value = lblWC.Text
    oCmdSql.Parameters.Add(paraWC)
    oCmdSql.CommandTimeout = 7200

    Try
        If oConnSql.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            oConnSql.Open()
        End If

        ' Adapter and Dataset
        oAdptSql.SelectCommand = oCmdSql
        oAdptSql.Fill(oDS, "dtList")
        oAdptSql.Fill(dt)

        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then

            Dim ProgessQty, WIPQty, WOQuantity As String
            Dim AgingWC, WOAging As Double
            'Dim WCAge, WoAge As TimeSpan
            Dim LeadTime As Double
            Dim Holiday As Integer
            Dim counter As Integer = 1
            Dim count As Integer = dt.Rows.Count - 1
            For i = 0 To count - 1


                ProgessQty = GETProgressWOQuantity(Trim(dt.Rows(i)(0).ToString))
                WOQuantity = Trim(dt.Rows(i)(1).ToString)
                WIPQty = CInt(ProgessQty)
                LeadTime = GetLeadTime(Trim(dt.Rows(i)(2).ToString), lblWC.Text)
                Holiday = CheckForHolidays(CDate(dt.Rows(i)(4).ToString), Now())
                WOAging = Format((DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, CDate(dt.Rows(i)(4).ToString), Now())) / 60 / 24, "0.0") - Holiday
                AgingWC = WOAging - LeadTime
                If AgingWC >= 5 And WIPQty > 0 Then

                    TempDT.Rows.Add(Trim(dt.Rows(i)(0).ToString), WOQuantity, Trim(dt.Rows(i)(2).ToString), Trim(dt.Rows(i)(3).ToString), WIPQty, Trim(dt.Rows(i)(5).ToString), Math.Round(CDbl(WOAging), 2), Math.Round(CDbl(AgingWC), 2), IIf(Math.Round(CDbl(AgingWC), 2) >= WCLimit, "Red", "Black"))
                    '
                    counter += 1
                Else
                End If

            Next

            Dim dataView As New DataView(TempDT)
            dataView.Sort = " AGINGATWC DESC"
            SortDT = dataView.ToTable()

            For j = 0 To SortDT.Rows.Count - 1
                myArray = myArray & "|" & j + 1
                myArray1 = myArray1 & "|" & Trim(SortDT.Rows(j)(0).ToString) 'WO
                myArray2 = myArray2 & "|" & Trim(SortDT.Rows(j)(1).ToString) 'WO QTY
                myArray3 = myArray3 & "|" & Trim(SortDT.Rows(j)(2).ToString) 'Part Number
                myArray4 = myArray4 & "|" & Trim(SortDT.Rows(j)(3).ToString) 'Description
                myArray5 = myArray5 & "|" & Trim(SortDT.Rows(j)(4).ToString) 'WIP QTY
                myArray6 = myArray6 & "|" & Trim(SortDT.Rows(j)(5).ToString) 'WIP DAYS
                myArray7 = myArray7 & "|" & Trim(SortDT.Rows(j)(6).ToString) 'WO Aging
                myArray8 = myArray8 & "|" & Trim(SortDT.Rows(j)(7).ToString) 'Aging at WC
                myArray9 = myArray9 & "|" & Trim(SortDT.Rows(j)(8).ToString) 'Color
                myArray10 = myArray10 & "|" & Trim(SortDT.Rows(j)(5).ToString) 'WONOTE
            Next

            dt.Clear()
            dt.Dispose()
            oCmdSql.Dispose()
            oConnSql.Close()

            ViewState.Clear()
            ViewState("JArray") = myArray
            ViewState("JArray1") = myArray1
            ViewState("JArray2") = myArray2
            ViewState("JArray3") = myArray3
            ViewState("JArray4") = myArray4
            ViewState("JArray5") = myArray5
            'ViewState("JArray6") = myArray6
            ViewState("JArray7") = myArray7
            ViewState("JArray8") = myArray8
            ViewState("JArray9") = myArray9
            ViewState("JArray10") = myArray10


        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        lblResult.Text = "Exception Message: " + ex.Message
    Finally

    End Try

End Sub
```

Now I realised if I run in Internet Explorer with `varchar(max)` it says

[image]

Comment: 1. What is the type of `WONOTE` in the DB, and 2. how are you getting the data from the server? (Please add to the question, not in a comment.)

Comment: `varchar(22000)` ?

Comment: **110 characters** for statement 1 and **10 characters** for statement 2 are the maximum it can get. if I put more than that it display nothing

Comment: i don't think your problem is displaying it actually selecting.... ensure you have selected your string correctly.

Comment: CR and LF characters are just spaces in most cases in HTML, so just return the value of the column without the cast and replaces. A `TEXT` column can be read as string without problem.

Comment: @Richard if I just select WONOTE without cast/replace/convert it give me this error `Exception Message: The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator. The text data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.` the solution is to convert datatype text into varchar. And, if I select other column that belongs to datatype varchar then it successfully display them. except for datatype text which cause me this problem.

Comment: You would need to drop the `distinct` – is the value of `WONOTE` significant for the distinct? Your problem is by casting to a specific length you are truncating the value of `WONOTE`.